# How do you square off only one corner of a div to be transparent in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to create a reusable widget. It will have some sort of background image, with a transparent text overlay. The background of the text overlay will be mostly square, but have one transparent corner. Is there an easy way to do this using CSS?

[image: Example of what widget should look like]

Comment: Can't be a border-radius right?

Comment: I thought that only created rounded borders?

Comment: you can use two background images, the picture and other for the square at bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient` background. Here is your reusable widget. Cheers!

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-widget {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.img-widget .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(118deg, transparent 0%, transparent 10%, #7AAD7A 10%, #7AAD7A 60%);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.img-widget .overlay:after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-widget">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  <div class="overlay">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#green-overlay {
   background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0) top left;
   add the rest of your css for this element
}
```

Something like this should work.  Just replace the rgba value and 30px with how deep you want the corner.

https://jsfiddle.net/snavy/acbo36n2/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following ([LIVE PEN HERE](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/LRbNOj)):

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    This div has a background image
    <div class="divider"><div id="rightDivider"><div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#rightDivider {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: -50px;
}
#rightDivider div{
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 100px 60px;
    border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 100%;
}
.divider {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.row {
    background: orange;
    position: relative; 
    height: 300px; 
    padding: 0;   
    margin: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using css3's -webkit-clip-path: polygon(); attribute to solve your issue.

See reference here: [CSS3 clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)